# Validação de formulário em modal com Vue e Vuelidate

Tags: javascript, vue.js, validação, bootstrap-4

tenho um formulário dentro de um modal e estou fazendo a validação dos campos (client side) utilizando o plugin [vuelidate](https://monterail.github.io/vuelidate/).

Uso o plugin [bootstrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/) para criar o modal, porém, quando implemento as validações do vuelidate, não consigo fazer com que o botão **Cancel** do modal limpe os erros de validações. Ele fecha o modal, limpa os campos (com this.variavel = ''), porém ainda mostra o texto do erro ou a borda vermelha indicativa e - entretanto, se eu pressionar **cancel** de novo, os campos voltam ao estado normal, sem indicativo de erro.

```
<b-modal
  id="signupFormModal"
  title="Crie a sua conta!"
  ref="modal"
  centered
  @ok="handleOk"
  @cancel="clearForm"
>
  <b-container fluid>
    <b-card>
      <b-form @submit.stop.prevent="handleSubmit">
        <b-form-group
          id="email"
          label-for="email"
        >
          <b-form-input
            ref="focusElement"
            autocomplete="username"
            id="email"
            type="email"
            v-model.trim="form.email"
            :state="$v.form.email.$dirty ? !$v.form.email.$error : null"
            @input="$v.form.email.$touch()"
            required
            placeholder="E-mail"
          />
        <small class="error">{{emailErrors}}</small>
        </b-form-group>
      </b-form>
    </b-card>
  </b-container>
</b-modal>
```

Meu objetivo é fazer com que o modal limpe os campos preenchidos com 1 click do botão apenas.
O código do script está abaixo:

```
import { required, minLength, sameAs, email } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'

export default {  
name: 'myForm',
  data: () => ({
    form: {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      confirmPassword: ''
    },
    show: true,
    nameState: null
  }),
  validations: {
    form: {
      email: { required, email },
      password: {
        required,
        minLength: minLength(6)
      },
      confirmPassword: {
        required,
        sameAsPassword: sameAs('password')
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
emailErrors () {
  if (!this.$v.form.email.$dirty) {
    this.returnNull()
    return ''
  } else if (!this.$v.form.email.required) {
    this.returnFalse()
    return 'E-mail é obrigatório'
  } else if (!this.$v.form.email.email) {
    this.returnFalse()
    return 'Exemplo: exemplo@exemplo.com'
  } else {
    this.returnNull()
  }
}
  },

methods: {
    clearForm () {
      /* Reset our form values */
      this.form.email = ''
      this.form.password = ''
      this.form.confirmPassword = ''
      this.$v.$reset()
    },
handleOk (evt) {
  // Prevent modal from closing
  evt.preventDefault()
  if (!this.$v.invalid) {
    this.handleSubmit()
  } else {
    this.$v.touch()
  }
},

handleSubmit () {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(this.form))
  this.clearForm()
  this.$refs.modal.hide()
},

focusMyElement (e) {
  this.$refs.focusElement.focus()
},

returnNull () {
  this.nameState = null
},
returnFalse () {
  this.nameState = false
},
returnTrue () {
  this.nameState = null
}
  }
}
```

Alguém com conhecimento em Vue, Bootstrap-Vue e Vuelidate, sabe me informar como resolver o problema?

Agradeço desde já a ajuda.